# Echo in sound when using headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

When I am using my headphones and listening to music on spotify I get an echo in the music. The background music is fine but the voice of the singer fluctuates. Mostly the voice decreases below the normal levels and it constantly echoes. I have tried fixing it through alsamixer and by installing spotify again but no solution.

*How do I stop the echo?*

Comment: General rule of thumb for such things:  try a different set of headphones in the same device and see if they have the same problem too; then try the original headphones in a different device and see if the problem moves with them.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it fixed after going through hundreds of lines of code and deleting and installing numerous software. the problem was solved when i slided the balance slider in sound settings to the right or left. it was initially in the middle which was causing the issue in the first place. after sliding the balance slider the issue was immediately fixed. no echo in sound and no bad sound quality. i suggest that people try this option.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you did to solve it? You said sliding this from the equilibrium position it caused problems, or did it cause problems because it was in the middle?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen, the balance should have moved all the sound to one ear, but I suspect it didn't actually do that or he wouldn't have thought it "fixed".  See my answer for a more likely explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting with the headphone cable plugged in. This solved it on my Ubuntu 19.04 machine...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a mechanical fault in the headphones or the jack.

There are three wires, left, common, and right.

If there is not a proper connection for the common wire, you'll still get sound, but it won't sound right.

What you'll hear is the difference between the left and right channels, with anything that is the same on both channels being cancelled out.  You'll hear the various instruments fairly well, as they tend to be more in one channel than the other, but central sounds, such as a singer's voice, will be almost eliminated, sounding like what you call an echo.

What your solution of shifting the balance to one side did was to provide no signal on one channel, so there was no cancellation, and the one channel you were listening to sounded correct.

If what you hear is the same in both ears, with no stereo effect, this is almost certainly the cause.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, toggling the bluetooth on/off works.

Command line:
    `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`

GUI: 
Settings->Bluetooth
Click on the bar in the top right corner.